# What does ホイっと mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, katakana

in a manga I was reading this expression appeared.
It was about a lazy girl, who was thinking about getting herself a boyfriend (so that he can do the house chores for her), and then her friend replies:

"そんなホイっと見つかるもんか"

From the context I'd just guess the sentence means something like "As if it would be so easy (for you to get a boyfriend)", but it's still bugging me what the "ホイ" here means.

It would be nice if someone could tell me! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the meaning is pretty much as you explain, except I would add that it implies doing something "carelessly" or "thoughtlessly". If you look up [ほいほい](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%84%E3%81%BB%E3%81%84) in the dictionary, you can find the relevant definition:

> 軽々しく物事を引き受けたり行なったりするさま。 「 －（と）二つ返事で引き受ける」 「何でも－（と）買ってやる」

Comment: Ah, ok, so it came from 'ほいほい', good to know^^  
Katakana always confuses me :-)  
So basically, it means 'taking something lightheartedly' or 'thinking something will be a easy thing to do', right?  
Thanks a lot for the help! :-)

Comment: @Mumei: It means `doing something easily` rather than `thinking`, also it implies "carelessly" and "thoughtlessly" (look up the definition for 軽々しい).

Comment: Hmm, ok, so the sentence would be something like "You think you'd just find one that easily in that carefree manner?", I guess?
Also, wanted to ask, is the っと just a 'spoken language' form of the usual と?

Comment: @Mumei: Where are you getting the `think` part from? I would translate it as `Yeah, like it's that easy to find one (a boyfriend)` (in a sarcastic manner). The `っと` is the same phenomenon as from `にこにこと笑う` to `にこっと笑う` which I believe happens in conversation (I don't know the exact details though).

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand^^
Thanks a lot! :-)